# Best way to implement a log with doctrine and sonata-admin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a case where I would like to log every change which happens on entities. I'm using sonata-admin with the doctrine admin bundle. I tried many things but I'm out of ideas what the best approach for this case would be.

The first try was creating a ChangeLog entity with the fields type (create / update), changes (array) and related entity class and id.

I setup a listener for the postUpdate und postPersist event:

```
appbundle.listen.ChangeLog:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\ChangeLogListener
    arguments: [@service_container]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate}
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist}
```

The related listener:

```php
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->buildLog($args, ChangeLog::TYPE_CREATE);
}

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args){
    $this->buildLog($args, ChangeLog::TYPE_UPDATE);
}

private function buildLog(LifecycleEventArgs $args, $type)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $clHelper = ChangeLogHelper::getInstance();

    if ($entity instanceof ChangeLog) return;

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $changes = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $cl = new ChangeLog();
    $cl->setUser($user);
    $cl->setDate(new \DateTime());
    $cl->setChangeset($changes);
    $cl->setType($type);
    $cl->setEntityName(get_class($entity));
    $cl->setDescription('');
    $cl->setEntityId($entity->getId());
    $cl->setRefGroup($clHelper->getRefId());

    $em->persist($cl);
    $em->flush();
}
```

That works for some entities but as soon as I have more relations i get the error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::__construct() ....
```

I found no way to solve this problem but I have the feeling that it is caused because the listener will be called many times (for the entity itself and each relation) and it would be better to flush at the end of all listeners instead of every time it is called, but I don't see any way to do that with the post event listener setup.

After hours of debugging I thought that it probably would be better anyway if I would have a polymorphic relation on the ChangeLog entity to every other entity and I could just use the prePersist / preUpdate listeners so I don't have to persist the object myself and just set it as relation on the changed object with a proper cascade. And I'm trying to avoid the use of the entityManager in doctrine events anyway. Well hours later I'm still stuck, I couldn't find a way with doctrine to have this kind of relation. Basically One-To-Many with an extra column where the target entity is defined.

I tried to get it to work with doctrine inheritance (STI and CTI) but then my log fields are on the entity itself and not separated anymore which I don't want. I tried to solve this without the owning side on the ChangeLog entity, but then I can't set the ChangeLog entity on the changed entity because it will be ignored. But I don't know how to define the owning side with a reference to basically every other entity and I don't think it is possible with doctrine right now.

With a mapped super class and just a OneToMany relation I will get a join table or join column for every entity which is kind of messy as well.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @BraianMellor i used https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAuditBundle or alternatively loggable from https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions . If you're using sonata admin the simplethings bundle is already supported: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/audit.html Boths are good examples how to integrate that functionality properly

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I´m not using sonata, but i´ll try EntityAuditBundle.

Comment: @BraianMellor both bundles work without sonata. EntityAuditBundle creates a seperate *_audit table for all the changes, which is nice if you have a lot of tables and data. Loggable works with annotations and therefor gives you much more control what is logged. But it collects all in one big table and the changeset as JSON which also has it's disadvantages. In the end it really depends on your usecase. But either way, if you still need a own solution you can take a look at both to see the doctrine impl. to archive this.

Comment: I got 2 questions: 1) how can I manage to audit roles of users, if there is no entity of UserRoles. 2) How can I see te history of changes? Don´t know how to manage routing with this :/

Comment: @BraianMellor sorry, not sure what you want to do. Both bundles allow you to log all changes to entities and save them to another table in the DB. Just query it.

Comment: EntityAuditBundle allow you to audit an entity. In the relation user->user_roles<-roles there is no user_roles entity. Symfony force you to do it that way. So how can I audit the roles changes of a user if there is no entity for that table.

Comment: @BraianMellor unfortunately many to many relationships aren't supported by both bundles. But for the loggable bundle that might be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871048/doctrine-2-log-changes-in-manytomany-relation